# Removing unnecessary nested index in array (generated by Cake PHP)

Tags: php, cakephp

The following question can either be solved by probably changing my use of the `find` method in Cake PHP OR using some PHP function.  I would prefer to solve it using Cake but it doesn't matter too much.  I have any array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Model] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [foo] => bar
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Model] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [foo] => something
                )

        ) .............
```

I just want to remove the `Model` index and just use the numeric one.  The following function generated this array:

```
$arr = $this->Model->find('all', array('contain' => false ) );
```

I probably need to change the `'contain'` part of the call.  Basically, in addition to the data that appears under each `Model` index, I also have a second and third model and the `contain = false` just restricts Cake from getting data from the current model (`Model`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think CakePHP's Set::combine function will help  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::combine :

```
$result = Set::combine($your_array, '{n}.Model.id', '{n}.Model.data');
```

This will result in:

```
 Array
 (
     [14] => Array
         (
             [foo] => bar
         )
     [15] => Array
         (
             [foo] => something
         )
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to write your own piece of code to modify your array , here is a function that will do what you want (you can improve it)

```
function reformArray($array,$modelName)
{

    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        $newArr[] = $arr[$key][$modelName];
    }

    return $newArr;
}
```

you have to pass your array and the Model Name to this function and will return you the result

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'group_id' => 1,
            'Data' => array(
                'user' => 'mariano.iglesias',
                'name' => 'Mariano Iglesias'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => 14,
            'group_id' => 2,
            'Data' => array(
                'user' => 'phpnut',
                'name' => 'Larry E. Masters'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => 25,
            'group_id' => 1,
            'Data' => array(
                'user' => 'gwoo',
                'name' => 'The Gwoo'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**RUN THIS TO REMOVE THE MODEL NAME USER**

```
Set::extract($a, '{n}.User');
```

**WILL RETURN THIS**

```
$a = array(
        array(

                'id' => 2,
                'group_id' => 1,
                'Data' => array(
                    'user' => 'mariano.iglesias',
                    'name' => 'Mariano Iglesias'
                )

        ),
        array(

                'id' => 14,
                'group_id' => 2,
                'Data' => array(
                    'user' => 'phpnut',
                    'name' => 'Larry E. Masters'
                )

        ),
        array(

                'id' => 25,
                'group_id' => 1,
                'Data' => array(
                    'user' => 'gwoo',
                    'name' => 'The Gwoo'
                )

        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 2:

```
$data = $this->Model->find('all');
$data = Set::extract('/Model/.', $data );
```

You can achieve this result by foreach also

```
foreach ($data as $k => &$t) {
    $t = $t['Model']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier with `Object`. Change the `Array` with `Object`.

Actually I had faced the same problem with `nested array` And I found the solution with [Set::map($array);](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::map)

If you don't want the `model_name` as `nested array`, You can prefer this solution.

```
$data = array(
    array(
        "IndexedPage" => array(
            "id" => 1,
            "url" => 'http://blah.com/',
            'hash' => '68a9f053b19526d08e36c6a9ad150737933816a5',
            'get_vars' => '',
            'redirect' => '',
            'created' => "1195055503",
            'updated' => "1195055503",
        )
    ),
    array(
        "IndexedPage" => array(
            "id" => 2,
            "url" => 'http://blah.com/',
            'hash' => '68a9f053b19526d08e36c6a9ad150737933816a5',
            'get_vars' => '',
            'redirect' => '',
            'created' => "1195055503",
            'updated' => "1195055503",
        ),
    )
);

$mapped = Set::map($data);

/* $mapped now looks like: */

    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_name_] => IndexedPage
                [id] => 1
                [url] => http://blah.com/
                [hash] => 68a9f053b19526d08e36c6a9ad150737933816a5
                [get_vars] =>
                [redirect] =>
                [created] => 1195055503
                [updated] => 1195055503
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_name_] => IndexedPage
                [id] => 2
                [url] => http://blah.com/
                [hash] => 68a9f053b19526d08e36c6a9ad150737933816a5
                [get_vars] =>
                [redirect] =>
                [created] => 1195055503
                [updated] => 1195055503
            )

    )
```

Answer (score -1):

you may do this :

```
$tmp = $this->Model->find('all', array('contain' => false ) );

$arr = $tmp['ModelName'];
```

Comment: you don't have to add th 'contain' to the query !

Comment: I always use `contain = array()` - but either way he has to add it if the default level of `recursive` is greater -1!

Comment: No, the array structure isn't like that.